# ASP.NET Core 8 - User.IsInRole not working

Tags: jwt, keycloak, asp.net-roles

I got all the role claims after successful login. But there must be a mapping mismatch between the name of the role claims and what ASP.NET expect.

User.IsInRole is not working, but I can get the roles with this code;

```
var roles = ((ClaimsPrincipal)identity).Claims.Where(m => m.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).Select(m => m.Value).ToList();
```

In services.AddAuthentication I have tried with the name "role" and "roles" for the mapping. Should be role as this is what I have in my JWT.

```
 options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "preferred_username",
                    RoleClaimType = "role",
                    ValidateIssuer = true
                };
```

This is part of my JWT

```
 "scope": "openid email profile",
    "sid": "8fac96c0-8c41-45f6-8074-7e5e18a35124",
    "email_verified": true,
    "role": [
      "ExternalPortfolioManager",
      "InternalFontViewer",
      "InternalDataManager",
      "ExternalTrader"
    ],
```

Feel that I am pretty close.

[image]

Comment: I fixed it like this:
 var roles = userIdentity.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "roles").ToList();
        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Value));
            userIdentity.RemoveClaim(role);
        }